# Python - Get name list of objects of a specified class in the namespace

Tags: python, variables, jupyter-notebook, namespaces, local-variables

I want to get a list of all dictionary objects that exist in the namespace.
I know that `%whos()` magic function will print the list, but as far as I could tell, it just prints and doesn't return anything.

Comment: Would `globals()` or `locals()` help? See [more](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-locals-function/#:~:text=Python%20locals()%20function%20returns,needed%20to%20execute%20a%20program.).

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: you can hack something like `[v for k,v in locals().items() if not k.startswith("__") and isinstance(v, dict)]` where `locals()` will give you the current namespace (e.g. the same as `globals()` if you are in the global scope), also, assuming you want to ignore various built-in dicts that you didn't define. Really, you should be keeping track of these sorts of things explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one function that would return a dataframe with variable names and their respective classes, which makes is **filterable** as well:

```
#%%% Objects in namespace

import pandas as pd

def get_env_vars(filter_for=None):
    globals_list = globals()
    var_list = [k for k in globals_list.keys() if (not k.startswith('_')) & (k not in ['In','Out','get_ipython','exit','quit'])]
    var_df = pd.DataFrame({'VarName': var_list})
    var_types = []
    for z in var_list:
        var_types.append(type(globals()[z]))
    var_df['VarClass'] = var_types
    var_df['VarClass'] = var_df['VarClass'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace("<class '", "").replace("'>", ""))
    if not pd.isna(filter_for):
        filter_for = str(filter_for).replace("<class '", "").replace("'>", "") if not isinstance(filter_for, str) else filter_for
        var_df = var_df[var_df['VarClass'] == filter_for].reset_index(drop=True)
        
    return var_df
```

Example:

```
a = 3
b = [1,2,3]
c = ['a','b']
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

get_env_vars()

>>> OUTPUT
#         VarName  VarClass
# 0            pd    module
# 1  get_env_vars  function
# 2             a       int
# 3             b      list
# 4             c      list
# 5             d      dict
```

**Get list objects only**

```
get_env_vars('list')

>>> OUTPUT
#   VarName VarClass
# 0       b     list
# 1       c     list
```